# Unable to update existing Android apk to Flutter apk

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I am unable to update my existing app in Android.

Previously, I have uploaded an app to play store that I developed using native Android(Java). Right now I am migrating it to Flutter. As I wanna test before publishing the apk, I did a local APK install to update my existing app on the phone but i received error "App not installed".

When i deleted the existing app and made a fresh install everything works fine, APK installed successfully.

I followed the steps provided by Google here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

**These are the steps I did:**

1) Generated the keystore file

2) Added settings configuration in build.gradle and key.properties file

3) Ensure my application ID is the same (which it is because it prompts me  update when installing apk)

4) run flutter build apk --release command

Comment: Check if you updated the version number to be higher. Also, I'm not sure if you can update a release version to debug version, or are they both signed release versions?

Comment: @aldobaie hi, yes i have already changed the version code to (+1) from my latest apk in play store. So in play store my version code is 43, i put 44 in build.gradle. I built both debug and release apk, and tried installing the apk manually to update my app but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't update the App on Play Store, I think the problem is on the first step that you have to use the same keystore file to update your app. Generating new keystore file is not acceptable even if application ID is the same.